# CSOM Change Field Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I am trying to change the list column name. Here is my code, it isn't working.
I added a content editor web part with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//js ref
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, "sp.js");  

 //Get our objects
 function initialize(){
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();        
  var web = context.get_web();                       
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("News");  
  var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("testar");

  context.load(field,"testar");

   context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,onListDataSucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataFailed)); 

function onListDataSucceeded(sender, args){
field.set_title("NewName");
field.update();
};

function onListDataFailed(sender,args){
alert('List Data fetch failed. ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
};
};
</script>
```

the error i get is:

> List Data fetch failed. The field or the proeprty testar does not
>   exist.nundefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your load is wrong like MdMazzotti pointed out. But you don't update your field, you'll have to load it into your `context` again and `executeQueryAsync` again inside your success function. But you could just load everything up in `initialize()`:

```
     function initialize(){
      var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();        
      var web = context.get_web();                       
      var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("News");  
      var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("testar");

      field.set_title("NewName");
      field.update();


      context.load(field);

       context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,onListDataSucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataFailed)); 
     }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, its working now. Im gonna take some hours to learn more of the csom in sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
context.load(field,"testar");
```

to this:

```
context.load(field);
```

Comment: i tryied it but nothing happens and no error..

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the Field Schema and updating the field name in it. Example:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),              //SP.ClientContext
    field = ctx.get_web()                              //SP.Web
               .get_lists()                            //SP.ListCollection
               .getByTitle('MyList')                   //SP.List
           .get_fields()                           //SP.FieldCollection
           .getByInternalNameOrTitle("Site");      //SP.Field
ctx.load(field, "SchemaXml");                          //load only SchemaXml
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var s = field.get_schemaXml(),
        s1 = s.replace('Title="PREVIOUSTITLE"', 
                           'ShowInDisplayForm="NEWTITLE"');
    field.set_schemaXml(s1);
    field.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync();
});
```

See more at http://chuvash.eu/2012/09/24/jsom-alter-a-columns-showindisplayform-property/

See this for Filed properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437580(v=office.15).aspx